# Show active page based on URL

Tags: jquery, css

I am adding a class to the menu item that has the current URL in the browser using the simple code below:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".menuzord-menu a").each(function(){ 
        if(jQuery(this).attr('href') == document.URL){
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
   });
```

This works but with a small delay before the active class is applied. Is this the correct way to achieve the desired effect and if so how can it be optimised so there isn't a delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try executing the `each()` function on window load:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    jQuery(".menuzord-menu a").each(function(){ 
      if(jQuery(this).attr('href') == document.URL){
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `foreach` loop, you can use this selector:

```
jQuery(".menuzord-menu a[href='" + document.URL + "']").addClass('active');
```

This should have better performance and may get rid of that small delay.

However, if you are still having the same delay, it is probably caused by something else (perhaps a CSS animation or a delay on javascript code execution).

Answer (score 0):

The delay is mainly caused by `.ready()` since it will wait until the DOM is fully loaded, which is usually a good practice but not in your case. The workaround I'd suggest is to run this is an inline script just after the `.menuzord-menu` element, without the `.ready()`:

```
jQuery(".menuzord-menu a").each(function(){ 
    if(jQuery(this).attr('href') == document.URL){
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```